# How do I stop search results listing pagination as duplicate content

Tags: ee2, pagination

I use pagination to list articles on topics and those written by a n individual writer.  How do I stop search results list the subsequent pages as duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

there is an answer on the EE forum which should help you out: https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/248465

Also, a link within the forum post says that Google won't punish you for duplicate content unless it's spammy: http://searchengineland.com/googles-matt-cutts-duplicate-content-wont-hurt-you-unless-it-is-spammy-167459

Answer (score 0):

I would consider the use of canonical meta data:
https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663744?hl=en

And then as above dynamic queries to alter page, titles and meta title data.